# How to monitor key presses in Python 3.7 using IDLE on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, python-3.7, keypress, python-idle, getch

Using Python 3.7 with IDLE, on Mac.  I want to be able to monitor key presses and immediately return either the character or its ASCII or Unicode value.  I can't see how to use pynput with Idle.  Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  IDLE uses the tkinter interface to the tcl/tk GUI framework.  The IDLE doc has a section currently title 'Running user code' with this paragraph.

> When Shell has the focus, it controls the keyboard and screen.  This is normally transparent, but functions that directly access the keyboard and screen will not work.  These include system-specific functions that determine whether a key has been pressed and if so, which.